# angular-material: can't center md-checkbox inside div

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

My task is to center an md-checkbox inside a div with flex.

I looked in the angular material website but still can't make it right.

```
<div class="main blue" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
   <div class="container yellow" layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="30">
      <md-checkbox class="check"></md-checkbox>
</div>
<div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="70">
      angular material
</div>
```

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1XzbxPeVwZCSGcxHHJxO?p=preview)

It is not perfectly in the center.

Is it because the md-chexbox has no label inside it?

what am i missing?

Comment: I have found `md-switch` has the proper alignment, so one option would be to use that instead of `md-checkbox`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/EgyVBY)

Make sure that your `div`s have closing tags in the correct place. Also, remove the bottom margin of the `md-checkbox` to have everything nicely lined up.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-padding>
  <div class="main blue" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
     <div class="container yellow" layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="30">
        <md-checkbox class="check"></md-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="70">
          angular material
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.check {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

It seems like your css doesn't perfectly center the checkbox inside the div.

I added this to your css:

    .check {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        width: 25px;
     }

The result is perect.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is realy only the margin-bottom.

Comment: Thanks. I was going nuts until I found the margin stuff!

Answer (score 0):

try this css class in the container div:

```
.container-checkbox-align-mat-form-field{
  display:flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```